# How to build tree structure from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have following table:

```
$arr = array(
  array('id'=>100, 'year'=>2019, 'month'=>9, 'name'=>'a'),
  array('id'=>101, 'year'=>2019, 'month'=>12, 'name'=>'b'),
  array('id'=>102, 'year'=>2020, 'month'=>1, 'name'=>'c'),
  array('id'=>103, 'year'=>2020, 'month'=>2, 'name'=>'d'),
);
```

With the code below

```
$tree = array();
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $tree[$row['year']] = array(
        $row['month'] => array (
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
        ),
    );
}
```

I would like to get following result - this structure as a tree:

```
Array
(
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 100
                    [name] => a
                )
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 101
                    [name] => b
                )
        )

    [2020] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                    [name] => c
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 103
                   [name] => d
                )
        )
)
```

Unfortunately I get only following one with single "branches":

```
Array
(
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 101
                    [name] => b
                )
        )

    [2020] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                   [id] => 103
                   [name] => d
                )
        )
)
```

What is missing here? why previous rows disappear from the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want the year and month as the main indexes, you need to use both of these when adding the data into the `$tree`...

```
$tree = array();
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $tree[$row['year']][$row['month']] = [   'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name']];
}
```

with your test data, this gives...

```
Array
(
    [2019] => Array
        (
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 100
                    [name] => a
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 101
                    [name] => b
                )

        )

    [2020] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 102
                    [name] => c
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 103
                    [name] => d
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have mistake in key's names - `bl_year, bl_month` not exist:

```
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $tree[$row['year']] = array(
        $row['month'] => array (
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Indeed I made mistake but in the post. In oryginal code there is no mistake here. I corrected the question.

Comment: this code doesn't answer the question, as the months are overriden for a given yer